# Uploading in heroku error. Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile. Uploading Heroku with git in spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku

The Full error is:
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project DAI: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]`

Im using git to put into the git that is provided

Full error part in cmd:

```
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  23.195 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-25T13:37:56Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project DAI: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 7443754b101ae5df5488e13d965acefaa6099876
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 7443754b101ae5df5488e13d965acefaa6099876
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to still-dusk-73288.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/still-dusk-73288.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git repo'
```

My full pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>



    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DAI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DAI</name>
    <description>Projecto de DAI</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!--<java.version>11</java.version>-->
        <repackage.classifier/>
        <spring-native.version>0.11.3</spring-native.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.44</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>ng-boot-starter-t
            <artifactId>spriest</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>${repackage.classifier}</classifier>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhance</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                            <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                            <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <properties>
                <repackage.classifier>exec</repackage.classifier>
                <native-buildtools.version>0.9.10</native-buildtools.version>
            </properties>
            <!--<dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${native-buildtools.version}</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-native</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>-->
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I already tried some solutions for the problem in stack overflow. But at the moment nothing resulted.
Can someone give some solutions to try to put in heroku? I need to put one api online as fast as possible. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This `invalid target release: 11` means you are not using a JDK11+ and your pom file contains `<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source` and `<source>17</source><target>17</target>` so the question is now: what target would like to build for and which JDK do you use?

Comment: I started the project in java 17, so i would like to keep going with the same version. How can i fix it in pom.xml

Comment: Decide which version you would like to build for (JDK version)... Remove the configuration for the compiler-plugin with source/target and use only `<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>` and `<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>` or in case you want to use JDK17 change them appropriately. Check if the heroku supports the appropriate JDK version...

Comment: Removed the configuration for the maven-compiler-plugin and tried to use only  the the source and target for both versions 11 and 17, but neither worked.

Comment: What does it mean: "neither worked"?

Comment: I tried t o put in version 11 and then in version 17 the source and the target and didn't worked changing the versions.

Comment: What is the error output etc. ? Please post those messages ...

Comment: Also you have to define the java version which should be used on heroku (see the answer post) java.runtime.version=11 !!!

Comment: Already made it, and still not working. I'm trying to re define the system variables of maven to see if i made something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably just a problem in version because heroku run by default version:

java: 8 & jdk: 1.8

you can change your project version and will work fine,
otherwise you can create a file `system.properties` in your root directory, and define the version you work with `java.runtime.version`, you can find the details here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support

Comment: Tried it, but the same error is appearing in the same version [invalid target release: 11]. I already added the file ```system.properties``` with the version of java.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its answer is a little bit late, i met the same problem like yours. but i changed my  `<java.version>17</java.version>`to `<java.version>1.8</java.version>`. and it can be run.
if someone has the same problem, you can try this.